# Drawing an Arc with a linear gradient brush using Microsoft Maui Graphics

Tags: c#, maui-windows

I'm having difficulty drawing a gradient colored arc with Microsoft Maui Graphics.

I'm using Windows Forms, Visual Studio Preview 5, and .NET Core 6.

Here is what I have tried:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Skia;

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MauiWinForms {
  public partial class Form1:Form {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void skglControl1_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Desktop.SKPaintGLSurfaceEventArgs e) {
      ICanvas canvas = new SkiaCanvas() { Canvas = e.Surface.Canvas };
      var canvasWidth = skglControl1.Width = 800;
      var canvasHeight = skglControl1.Height = 800;
      canvas.FillColor = Colors.LightGrey;
      canvas.FillRectangle(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

      canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
      canvas.DrawRectangle(1, 1, 800-2, 800-2);

      var centerX = canvasWidth / 2;
      var centerY = canvasHeight / 2;
      canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Teal;
      canvas.StrokeSize = 10;
      var X = centerX - 200;
      canvas.DrawArc(X, 0, 400, 400, 0, 90, false, false);

      var linearGradientPaint = new LinearGradientPaint {
        StartColor = Colors.White,
        EndColor = Colors.Green,
        StartPoint = new Point(0, 0),
        EndPoint = new Point(1, 0)
      };
      var myRectangle = new RectangleF(X, 0, 410, 410);
      canvas.SetFillPaint(linearGradientPaint, myRectangle);
      canvas.DrawArc(X, 0, 400, 400, 0, -90, false, false);
    }

    private void skglControl1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => skglControl1.Invalidate();

  }
}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, the linear gradient is not applied.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Comment: Apparently the second `DrawArc` call has absolutely no effect, I only see the first teal one. I don't have Maui installed atm, but check if your second call is correct. Also maybe sketch in Photoshop how you want it to look so it helps us figuring out what to do.

Comment: I am, as said I just don't have _installed_ it right now. I've pointed out what to check for anyway. Good luck.